Initialize a structure in Release build with Visual Studio 2022
given the structure
typedef struct foo_s
{
    uint32_t a;
    bool b;
} foo;

Visual Studio 2022 allocates 8 bytes for its storage, even if bool has a size of 1.
Following code returns true in Debug and false in Release:
bool Compare( void )
{
    foo f1 = { 3, true };
    foo f2 = { 3, true };
    return memcmp( & f1, & f2, sizeof( foo ) ) == 0 ? true : false;
}

The reason is obvious: all 8 bytes of foo are cleared by compiler to 0 in Debug,
the Release build does not (speed optimization) and the last 3 bytes of the 8
reserved for the structure are just garbage (not initialized memory on stack).
Question: is any way to convince the compiler to initialize the entire struct in Release builds?
This code compiles as C++.
Following solutions exist and are not acceptable to me:
bool Compare( void )
{
    foo f1 = { 0 };
    f1.a = 3;
    f1.b = true;
    foo f2 = { 0 };
    f2.a = 3;
    f2.b = true;
    return memcmp( & f1, & f2, sizeof( foo ) ) == 0 ? true : false;
}

bool Compare( void )
{
    foo f1;
    memset( & f1, 0, sizeof( foo ) );
    f1.a = 3;
    f1.b = true;
    foo f2;
    memset( & f3, 0, sizeof( foo ) );
    f2.a = 3;
    f2.b = true;
    return memcmp( & f1, & f2, sizeof( foo ) ) == 0 ? true : false;
}


A side note: since you tagged C++, there's no need for typedef struct foo_s .... You can use struct foo { ... };. Also you shouldn't use memcmp for checking equality. That's what operator== is for.

Related: Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?

The fallow bytes in the structure are for padding and alignment.  They are an implementation detail, and not accessible by the C++ abstract machine.  Which means they have implementation specific behavior if accessed (probably arbitrary garbage values that may unreliably mutate because they have no coherence).

I know that: 1) memcmp shall not be used to compare structs, 2) the size of a struct is not (always) equal to the sum of sizeof of each member and 3) about padding and alignment. Unfortunately, I need a solution to my problem.

Side note: x == 0 ? true : false is an unnecessarily verbose way of writing x == 0.

My examples are a proof of concept, which reproduce the problem. Unfortunately, and I cannot change that, the real code gets some void* to unknown data structs together with their sizes (yeah, I know, the worst and ugliest style ever). That implies memcmp().

use #pragma pack(1)

@AhmedAEK I'm not allowed to mess with the code, so no #pragma pack(1). Changing a bool to uint32_t would mess with variable's semantic.

There is no way to get the compiler to set the padding bytes, because as far as the C++ Standard is concerned they don't exist.  A direct write to the memory of the whole structure (which you have already ruled out) is the only way.

If you don't know the layout of the structs, how do you expect memcmp to be able to tell real bytes from padding? If you swap b and a around you get 3 padding bytes in the middle of the struct.

@Botje That's the problem. As Richard Critten said, padding bytes should not be there at all. They are required for data alignment and/or speed. AFAIK, on x86 is faster to read DWORDs aligned in memory as an 8-bit value, that's why the compiler adds padding in the first place. On other architectures padding is mandatory for data alignment, otherwise you got a misaligned data exception. The problem is that a debug build initializes the entire memory allocated for the structure with 0 to help debugging (who didn't like to bite a null pointer after all? :) ), but I need this in release too.

I wonder that you claim unused padding bytes are filled with 0s on your side. This is not what I'm used to in VS (Debug build). For your foo f1 = { 3, true };, I got 03 00 00 00 01 cc cc cc in VS 2019, and this is exactly what I expected to get. (What are the debug memory fill patterns in Visual Studio C++ and Windows?)


Question: is any way to convince the compiler to initialize the entire struct in Release builds? This code compiles as C++.

This is at odds with C compatibility in terms of layout and performance.  A stack struct is created on the stack, with left over memory from some previous variable, or function call.
The C++ system initializes the used parts of the structure - giving defined visible behaviour which is complete.
Looking at the memory layout of the structure, you become an unreliable observer, looking at the undefined state of the machine you are running on.
In debug mode, the compiler may make consistent changes - initializing memory to 0xcc to create faults when un-initialized pointer are used, but again it is modifying the unobservable data.
